# How to display block to the nodes of specific content type?

Tags: blocks

I have created a content type "test". I also created a block "Search". I like to display the block only to nodes of the content type.

I configure the block and under Show block on specific pages >  Only the listed pages > Entered

> test/*

. It did not work. How can I display the block only to the nodes of the "test" content type?

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the block configuration page, select the content type like this picture:

[image]